# How can I display products of a specific subcategory?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, categories

I want to display the list of products of a specific sub-category of a category. My code is as following:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'product_cat' => 'Featured', 'orderby' => 'Desc', 'Parent' => 40);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="hmprdimgsmall">
             <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID )) echo get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog'); else echo '<img src="'.woocommerce_placeholder_img_src().'" />'; ?>
            <div class="hmprdname"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

For 'Parent' => 35 it worked. But returning same result for  'Parent' => 40
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new loop for that. Here's the code I use for displaying products from a specific category on the home page:

```
<ul class="products">
<?php
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'product_cat' => 'shoes', 'orderby' => 'rand' );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>
    <h2>Shoes</h2>
    <li class="product">
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $loop->post->ID ) ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr($loop->post->post_title ? $loop->post->post_title : $loop->post->ID); ?>">
            <?php woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash( $post, $product ); ?>
            <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID )) echo get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog'); else echo '<img src="'.woocommerce_placeholder_img_src().'" alt="Placeholder" width="300px" height="300px" />'; ?>
            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            <span class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></span>
        </a>
        <?php woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart( $loop->post, $product ); ?>
    </li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</ul><!--/.products-->
```

This is my working code
Thanks